# Changing the logo of VLC player embedded in HTML page

Tags: html, embed, vlc, embedding

I have embedded the VLC player to a webpage and I would like to know if it's possible to change the "cone" logo with a different image. I'm using VLC in order to play a multicast stream (only audio).

I looked at the VLC webplugin documentation and found this: http://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:WebPlugin#Logo_Object

I'm not sure how it works. This is what I have until now but does not work and the logo stays the same.

```
<html><head><title>Radio</title></head><body>

<embed type="application/x-vlc-plugin" pluginspage="http://www.videolan.org"
version="VideoLAN.VLCPlugin.2"  
width="300px"  height="300px" id="vlc" windowless="true" loop="yes" autoplay="no"
enablejavascript="true" allowfullscreen="false" target="rtp://@:port/" id="vlc">
</embed>

<script>
     var vlc = document.getElementById("vlc");
     vlc.video.logo.file("pic.png");
</script>

</body></html>
```

Any suggestions and help are very much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
<embed type="application/x-vlc-plugin" 
       pluginspage="http://www.videolan.org"
       version="VideoLAN.VLCPlugin.2"
       width="300px"  
       height="300px" 
       id="vlc" 
       windowless="true" 
       loop="yes" 
       autoplay="no"
       enablejavascript="true" 
       allowfullscreen="false" 
       target="rtp://@:port/">
</embed>
```